# useSignal re-rendering state while updating a value in an object, why?

Tags: reactjs, dom, signals

I noticed that when I update a single value in signal variable such as ( const count = useSignal(0) )the DOM doesn't re-renders, but when I update the value of an object, then the DOM is re-rendering every time.
Why is that happening?

[code-sandbox link:](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fog-8lzkmv?file=/src/components/CartSignal.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are using items.value while the component renders. If that value (array itself) changes, the component rerenders. If you use count.value instead of count, the component will rerender when count changes as well.

`items.value.map` returns new array, so there is no way to make that skip rerender with that implementation. If you move that loop logic in new component and pass items to it as prop, then only the new component will rerender